# join lines

Tags: c#, richtextbox, paragraph

on a windows form, i have RichTextBox, with some text, in several lines. and one button on a form.

i wolud like when i click on that button, to join all richtextbox of lines in one line, but not to loose text style (like font family, color, etc.)

i can not do it with Replace, like \r\n, and not with the Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")........
:-((

i have also tryed to replace \par and \pard, but still no luck.......

please help!!!

---

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

this one is not ok, because with that loose font definitions (color, bold, undesline etc).

ok, again to be more specific...

i have RichTextBox control, with 4 lines of text:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

line 3 is colored red.

i need to get following:

```
line 1 line 2 line 3 line 4
```

(and that "line 3" be red as it was before).

when i try with

richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");

... i get:

```
line 1
line 2   
line 34
```

"line 2" is colored red.

what do i have to do, to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not very very clear. What happens when you do Replace? Can you include a 'before' and 'after' example of what you want?

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
        // Create a temporary buffer - using a RichTextBox instead
        // of a string will keep the RTF formatted correctly
        using (RichTextBox buffer = new RichTextBox())
        {
            // Split the text into lines
            string[] lines = this.richTextBox1.Lines;
            int start = 0;

            // Iterate the lines
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                // Ignore empty lines
                if (line != String.Empty)
                {
                    // Find the start position of the current line
                    start = this.richTextBox1.Find(line, start, RichTextBoxFinds.None);

                    // Select the line (not including new line, paragraph etc)
                    this.richTextBox1.Select(start, line.Length);

                    // Append the selected RTF to the buffer
                    buffer.SelectedRtf = this.richTextBox1.SelectedRtf;

                    // Move the cursor to the end of the buffers text for the next append
                    buffer.Select(buffer.TextLength, 0);
                }
            }

            // Set the rtf of the original control
            this.richTextBox1.Rtf = buffer.Rtf;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The TextBox control has its own methods for finding and replacing text. Take a look at this article (it's VB.NET but I hope you will get the idea): http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/findandriplace_rtb.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I bet you're just calling Replace on the text string, what you need to do is something like this:

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

The key here is that you need to assign the result of the function to the text of the rich text box, otherwise nothing happens. See, strings are *immutable* and whenever you perform an operation on one you must assign the result of the operation to something (even the original variable will work) otherwise nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

I think this help you:

```
StringBuilder strbld = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < this.richTextBox1.Text.Length; i++)
{
   char c = this.richTextBox1.Text[i];

   if (c.ToString() != "\n")
      strbld.Append(c);
}

MessageBox.Show(strbld.ToString());
```

ok, ChrisF is right. How about this:

```
string strRtf = richTextBox1.Rtf.Replace("\\par\r\n", " ");
strRtf = strRtf.Replace("\\line", " ");
richTextBox2.Rtf = strRtf;
```

:-|

Comment: This will just concatenate the text, and strip the formatting